# AttributeError: module 'socketserver' has no attribute 'ForkingMixIn'

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

First I tried the **SocketServer** class. Then I got to know that SocketServer is available in Python2. For Python3 you need to make it lower case such as **socketserver**. I am trying to implement a Socket server which can respond to multiple threads and doesnt block the call.

Following is the code for Server

```
class ForkingServer(socketserver.ForkingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
  pass
```

[image]
But it gives the above mentioned error. Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: As long as you `import socketserver` this works for me using Python 3.6.3

Comment: @LukeSmith I am using Anaconda and Spyder. The version is 3.6.0 for Python and Anaconda is 4.3.1. Should it matter?

Comment: @LukeSmith I also tried with 3.6.3. It doesnt work for me.

Comment: Did you create a module yourself called "socketserver.py"?

Comment: @Iguananaut no. It is pythons standard module

Comment: What do you get if you run `dir(socketserver)` after you've imported it?

Comment: @LukeSmith I havent tried that. But as pointed out by Iguananaut this class is not supported on windows. What should I use in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Oh, I just realized from the screenshot that you're on Windows.  The `ForkingMixIn` class is not available on Windows because there is no `fork()` on Windows.  This is also mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.ForkingMixIn).

Comment: you are right. This class is not available for windows. But then what is available for windows ?

Comment: You can still use `ThreadingMixIn` or consider using `asyncio`.